# Is it possible to be prompted for VSTO ClickOnce update?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-installer, vsto, clickonce, setup-project

I've created a Word Add-In for 2007-2010 using Visual Studio 2010, and I'm using ClickOnce deployment; however, I'd like to at least prompt the user before performing the update, something as simple as "There is a new version available, would you like to update?  Y/N".

I can see that non-Office ClickOnce applications have this ability, but I can find nothing anywhere about doing this on Office Add-Ins.  I also see tons of people asking this question, but nobody seems to have an answer, and I find it interesting that the number of people asking this question seems to trail off after 2008...does this mean that there's a way to go about this that I'm missing?

Comment: Did you ever find an answer? The links provided by Kiru don't seem to give an explanation on how to prompt a user, before installing VSTO ClickOnce update.

Comment: Unfortunately, no, I never found anything definitive.

Answer (score 0):

Similar question over [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsto/thread/5370eb94-1ed0-457c-8a39-40ff6d871c12/)

Check Updating Solutions section [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb821233%28v=office.12%29.aspx)